# Codeigniter Active Record select on multiple databases

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, select

I need some help to figure out how to make a select from tables in multiple databases using Active Record in Codeigniter.

In details: I have two database; in the first one there is a table named users with all details about user (first name, last name and so on); in the second database there is a table named credit where there are credit info about each user; the user_id is the key that links the tables.

In the contruct Model I have:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->rci_db = $this->load->database('dev', TRUE);
    }
```

The query to select the data is:

```
$this->db->select (" 
            $this->t_users.user_id,
            $this->t_users.username,
            $this->t_users.first_name,
            $this->t_users.last_name,
            $this->t_users.email,
            $this->t_users.lastlogin,
            $this->t_contributers.user_id AS credit
            ");
        $this->db->from($this->t_users);
        $this->db->join($this->rci_db.$this->t_contributers, "$this->t_contributers.user_id = $this->t_users.user_id");
```

The query doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
Error Number: 1146

Table 'gavsit_data.rci_imgcontributers' doesn't exist

SELECT `users`.`user_id`, `users`.`username`, `users`.`first_name`, `users`.`last_name`, `users`.`email`, `users`.`lastlogin`, `rci_imgcontributers`.`user_id` AS `credit` FROM `users` JOIN `rci_imgcontributers` ON `rci_imgcontributers`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id` ORDER BY `id` ASC

Filename: models/adm/Users_model.php
```

Thanks a lot for any hint...I really don't know how to figure out this issue.

EDIT:
I've edited the code splitting the select query, the error has gone but I got no data from the second DB:

```
   $this->db->select (" 
            $this->t_users.id,
            $this->t_users.username,
            $this->t_users.first_name,
            $this->t_users.last_name,
            $this->t_users.email,
            $this->t_users.last_login,
            $this->t_users.active
            ");
        $this->rci_db->select("
            $this->t_contributers.user_id,
            $this->t_contributers.cbtid
            ");
        $this->db->from($this->t_users);
        $this->rci_db->join("$this->t_contributers", "$this->t_contributers.user_id = $this->db.$this->t_users.id", 'left');
```

Comment: I don't think what you're trying to do is possible.

Comment: Where does `gavsit_data.rci_imgcontributers come` from?  In MySQL, virtually any place you can specify table `T`, you can specify `D.T` -- to say which database `D` that table `T` is in.

Comment: Thanks for feedback Rick; about your question: gavsit_data.rci_imgcontributers comes from the latest row in select code. The $this->t_contributers refers to the table rci_imgcontributers but this one lies on the second DB; so I tried to edit the select code in the following way: $this->rci_db.$this->t_contributers.user_id AS credit .... but got the same error :(